# C# - most efficient way of measuring ellapsed time

Tags: c#, performance, time, memory-efficient

I am working on a C# console application in which I need to know the ellapsed time since the program has started.
I have a variable that stores the time on start (`DateTime now = DateTime.Now;`)

What is the most efficient way of measuring the ellapsed time?
**The ellapsed time can be hours - this is why I am concerned about efficiency and memory usage.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var elapsed = DateTime.Now - now;`, this produces a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0), and there is absolutely nothing to be concerned about, the passage of time is very efficient, it 'just happens'.

Comment: Why all the concern about efficiency here? Are you just trying to be efficient, or is there some particular need you're trying to optimize for?

Comment: StopWatch : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0.

Comment: This is probably a borderline repeat question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686928/using-stopwatch-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. Measuring a time span does not use any resources, as it just compares now with then.

```cs
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

// do some heavy calculation

TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now - start; // get the time that elapsed
```

This does not use any resources except the variable for the start, which is just a 64 bit counter.

Note that for short timespans you're better off using `Stopwatch`, as this is not subject to time adjustments that may happen between start and now.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the current time from the time the program started. This will return a `TimeSpan` which exposes [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days?view=net-5.0) like [`TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=net-5.0) which you can use to calculate the elapsed time.

```
// on start
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

// later on, to see hours elapsed since then
var elapsed = (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalHours;
```

Comment: adding an explanation is often helpful